# I was trying to use mongoose insertMany to solve a problem but is given problem

Tags: mongoose-schema

This is the code for Mongoose FruitDB where i was trying to use insertMany() inorder  to solve the challenge but is given the error you saw in other image.

`[ [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqnB2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l6cr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjfV0.png)`

```
[This is the error message am getting i dont know if anyone can help me with it ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwa2f.png)
```